# MySQL server has gone away during crawling in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, web-crawler, www-mechanize

I use WWW::Mechanize library to get the content of URLs and save their data into mysql tables. But when the page's content is too large, it gives this error message:

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL server has gone away at
>   F:\crawling\perl_tests\swc2.pl line 481.

For example, it throws this error when I try to extract the content of this page: https://www.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebService.asmx?wsdl

I added this code as well, but it still does not work

```
$connection->{max_allowed_packet}=1000000000;
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you using the latest DBI and DBD::mysql? It should have mysql_auto_reconnect enabled.

If you're using mysql under forks, you may need to set

```
$dbh->{InactiveDestroy} = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [DBIx::Connector](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aConnector).  From the docs:

> You can store the connection somewhere in your app where you can
>   easily access it, and for as long as it remains in scope, it will try
>   its hardest to maintain a database connection. Even across forks
>   (especially with DBI 1.614 and higher) and new threads, and even calls
>   to $conn->dbh->disconnect. When you don't need it anymore, let it go
>   out of scope and the database connection will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
max_allowed_packet=32M
```

in MySQL configuration file