# How to manage database connection to MySQL server in perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL server has gone away during crawling in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414682/mysql-server-has-gone-away-during-crawling-in-perl)

I am using following script to create database connection to my mysql server.

```
my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:dbname=$dbname;$dbhost";
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    $dsn, $dbuser,
    $dbpasswd,
    {
        PrintError         => 1,
        Warn               => 1,
        AutoCommit         => 1,
        ShowErrorStatement => 1
    }
);
```

The main script which usage this connection is a long running script. Sometime in the execution the program gets failed with error message.

```
MySQL server has gone away
```

I am new to `Perl`, and am not able to see any issue with the database connection.

Comment: it looks ok and the error message suggests that the issue *could* be not the way you do the connection; maybe more details are needed to have a picture of the problem. (are you opening several connections without closing them? — there's a max connections limits in MySql ... is your `$dbhost` always available? — network problems?... more details needed)

Comment: No, This is the single connection instance, And based on some condition this connection is used to fetch data.

Comment: does that answers solved the problem of the user? we don't know, but likely they do.

Comment: @ShinTakezou, Yes, `dbhost` is always available.

Comment: @Shades try the suggestion of the "duplicate" question, maybe `$dbh->{InactiveDestroy} = 1;` - more likely mysql_auto_reconnect, ie `$dbh->{mysql_auto_reconnect} = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this thread : http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=317168

This discusses the way to deal with "MySQL server has gone away" problem. Basically you would need to check the status of `$dbh` before firing your query.

```
$dbh ||= DBI->connect("connection string", "username", "password");
```